# Overloaded URL into Create() method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, controller

I have my Overloader URL wich contains the number `id` at the end.
I am currently doing a number of different things with the `id` in my code.

But now I want to set it to the `SurveyID` value, when passing it to database.
I am having some difficulty seeing the different Strings that are included in the `ViewBag`s and `Binds`.

This is my `Controller` code:

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
{
    //GET QUESTIONS FROM DATABASEDEPENDING ON SURVEYID
    var survey = db.Surveys.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SurveyID == id);
    if (survey != null)
    {
        ViewBag._CurrentSurveyID = id;
//DOING STUFF

    }
    else if (survey == null) {                 
//DOING STUFF
    }

    ////ATTEMPT
    //string currentSurveyID = ViewBag._CurrentSurveyID;
    //ViewBag.SurveyID = new SelectList(db.Surveys, currentSurveyID, "SurveyName");

    //STANDARD CODE
    ViewBag.SurveyID = new SelectList(db.Surveys, "SurveyID", "SurveyName");

    return View();

}
```

I am able to use my `id` value to a lot of success when loading my Create() page. (Above).

But I need help to include the `id` value when Create() database input. (Below).
Where do the string values in the Bind come from? The View, i'm assuming?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]        
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "IntroResponseID,SurveyID,IntroAnswer1,IntroAnswer2,IntroAnswer3,IntroAnswer4,IntroAnswer5,IntroFreeText,IntroTime")] IntroResponse introResponse)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.IntroResponses.Add(introResponse);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.SurveyID = new SelectList(db.Surveys, "SurveyID", "SurveyName", introResponse.SurveyID);
        return View(introResponse);
    }
```

What is the correct way to include `id` as my `SurveyID` input?

**EDITED with more info:**
`View`:

If `id` is in URL, code go into the first if. If there is no `id` in URL; show the Dropdown to pick SurveyID.
Notice that the Dropdown works perfectly to select SurveyID.
But I am as you can see attempting to set SurveyID to my ViewBag code in the hidden `@ActionLink`, this fails.

```
@{
            if (ViewBag.vbgSenderContactName != null || ViewBag.vbgSenderCompanyName != null || ViewBag.vbgResponderContactName != null || ViewBag.CounsultantName != null)
            {                
            string _stringSurveyID = @ViewBag._CurrentSurveyID.ToString();

            @ViewBag._CurrentSurveyID;
            <div class="hidden">
                @Html.ActionLink("SurveyID", "", new { value = "_stringSurveyID" })
            </div>                     
            }
            else
            {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SurveyID, "Välj undersökning", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("SurveyID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SurveyID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            }
        }
```

`Model` property:

```
[Required()]
public int SurveyID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("SurveyID")]
[Display(Name = "Välj undersökning")]
public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you show you view? If you're building a drop-down list using html helpers everything should work out of the box

Comment: What property are you binding the selected survey to?

Comment: It does work to use the DropDown, yes. But I want to direct your attention to the `if` space in my View where I simply want SurveyID to be set to the value of the overloaded URL ( `string _stringSurveyID = @ViewBag._CurrentSurveyID.ToString();` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a value to `ActionLink` then you need to use the exact property name as in your action method.

```
@Html.ActionLink("SurveyID", "", new { id= ViewBag._CurrentSurveyID})
```

Fixed small typo

Comment: That is a great advice. But I still have the 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' -Error.

The SurveyID ViewBag contains a System.Web.Mvc.SelectList, not a int value. Is this the way it should be?

Comment: @JuliusHolmberg you need to use `ViewBag._CurrentSurveyID` as you host your id there. `ViewBag.SurveyID` contains a `SelectList`. not an `int`

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to **Vsevolod Goloviznin**

Working code:

**Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult Create(int? id)
    {
        //GET QUESTIONS FROM DATABASEDEPENDING ON SURVEYID
        var survey = db.Surveys.FirstOrDefault(s => s.SurveyID == id);
        if (survey != null)
        {
            string stringID = id.ToString();
            ViewBag._currentSurveyID = int.Parse(stringID);
```

**View:**

```
        if (ViewBag.vbgSenderContactName != null || ViewBag.vbgSenderCompanyName != null || ViewBag.vbgResponderContactName != null || ViewBag.CounsultantName != null)
        {

    <div class="hidden">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SurveyID, "Välj undersökning", htmlAttributes: new { id = ViewBag._currentSurveyID })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("SurveyID", null, htmlAttributes: new { id = ViewBag._currentSurveyID })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SurveyID, "", new { id = ViewBag._currentSurveyID })
                    </div>
                </div>
        }
        else if (1 > 2)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SurveyID, "Välj undersökning", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("SurveyID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SurveyID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
}
```

I Think that my ActionLink fails to fold all of the many properties derived from the `SurvedID`.
For this reason I did use a "standard" DropDown. But hidden.
Notice that I forced the `ViewBag._currentSurveyID` to become an `int` in the Controller